# Migrating jsps from Struts 1.x to Struts 2.x

Tags: java

There is a Struts application that needs to be migrated to Struts 2.The Struts 1.x has jsps which has html code in the form of `<html:form>`, `<html:hidden>` etc.Should these be converted to Struts 2.x tags like `<s:form>`, `<s:hidden>` etc or can I leave the tags as they are?

Answer (score 0):

When migrating from Struts 1 to S2 the View is most difficult part, you have to rewrite S1 tags to S2 tags. for example

Struts 1:

```
<logic:equal value="1234" name="custDetail" property="ackMsg">
    <% String str = "valid" %>
</logic:equal>
```

Struts 2 :

```
<s:if test="custDetail.ackMsg == '1234'">
    <% String str = "valid" %>
</s:if>
```

and the tags you are talking about, you'll have to convert them

Comment: Thanks.I was aware of the tags to be converted as shown in your example above.But was not sure of the ones like <html:form> etc.I guess they have to be converted too .Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thanks.Related to the above I am not able to prepoulate a text field using the value in a bean.For example,I am trying to use the following: <s:textfield value=“#{beanName.startDate}”.But the value remains blank.

Comment: But when I use a <s:property for the same I get the value.Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Please ignore.I think I found the issue.